# Efficient approach to multithreaded set difference

Tags: c#, multithreading, performance, linq, monitor

I have a finite set of consumer threads each consuming a job. Once they process the job, they have a list of subjobs that were listed in the consumed job. I need to add the subjobs from that list that I don't already have in the database. There are 3 million in the database, so getting the list of which ones aren't already in the database is slow. I don't mind each thread blocking on that call, but since I have a race condition (see code) I have to lock them all on that slow call, so they can only call that section one at a time and my program crawls. What can I do to fix this so the threads don't slow down for that call? I tried a queue, but since the threads are pushing out lists of jobs faster than the computer can determine which ones should be added to the database, I end up with a queue that keeps growing and never empties.

My code:

```
IEnumerable<string> getUniqueJobNames(IEnumerable<job> subJobs, int setID)
{
    return subJobs.Select(el => el.name)
        .Except(db.jobs.Where(el => el.set_ID==setID).Select(el => el.name));
}

//...consumer thread i
lock(lockObj)
{
    var uniqueJobNames = getUniqueJobNames(consumedJob.subJobs, consumerSetID);
    //if there was a context switch here to some thread i+1
    //   and that thread found uniqueJobs that also were found in thread i
    //   then there will be multiple copies of the same job added in the database.
    //   So I put this section in a lock to prevent that.
    saveJobsToDatabase(uniqueJobName, consumerSetID);
}
//continue consumer thread i...
```

Comment: it's not clear to me what you are trying todo, can you explain again WHAT you are trying todo, but without the info on HOW you currently do it, just so the actual tasks becomes more clear

Comment: Can't you first get the list of existing jobs, then compile a list of "new" subjobs in parallel and, finally, save the new jobs?

Comment: The problem is I don't know which ones are new unless I compare them against the database using except. I could compile a list of all subjobs that come up but when I finally want to compare that list against the database, it wouldn't finish by the time the next list came around. They're building up faster than I can run the Except method regardless if I cache the list for later or run it immediately. Actually if I run it immediately, the consumers would run faster and the issue is compounded. I'm guessing there's some datastructure that could help, or just a different algorithm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than going back to the database to check for uniqueness of job names you could the relevant info into a lookup data structure into memory, which allows you to check the existence much faster:

```
Dictionary<int, HashSet<string>> jobLookup = db.jobs.GroupBy(i => i.set_ID)
    .ToDictionary(i => i.Key, i => new HashSet<string>(i.Select(i => i.Name)));
```

This you only do once. Afterwards every time you need to check for uniqueness you use the lookup:

```
IEnumerable<string> getUniqueJobNames(IEnumerable<job> subJobs, int setID)
{
    var existingJobs = jobLookup.ContainsKey(setID) ? jobLookup[setID] : new HashSet<string>();

    return subJobs.Select(el => el.Name)
        .Except(existingJobs);
}
```

If you need to enter a new sub job also add it to the lookup:

```
lock(lockObj)
{
    var uniqueJobNames = getUniqueJobNames(consumedJob.subJobs, consumerSetID);
    //if there was a context switch here to some thread i+1
    //   and that thread found uniqueJobs that also were found in thread i
    //   then there will be multiple copies of the same job added in the database.
    //   So I put this section in a lock to prevent that.
    saveJobsToDatabase(uniqueJobName, consumerSetID);

    if(!jobLookup.ContainsKey(newconsumerSetID))
    {
        jobLookup.Add(newconsumerSetID, new HashSet<string>(uniqueJobNames));
    }
    else
    {
        jobLookup[newconsumerSetID] = new HashSet<string>(jobLookup[newconsumerSetID].Concat(uniqueJobNames)));
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice solution. I would much rather use memory like this than to have a NlogN lookup everytime. I'll write a custom version of this datastructure that synchronizes new adds with the database

Comment: My advise is to not over complicate the data structure too much, handle DB/memory it separately, makes debugging issue much simpler